# How can I extract numbers from an NSString?

Tags: ios, nsstring

I have an NSString data with the following and similar formats:

```
10mm x 1000mm  
4mm x 20mm  
50mm x 200mm  
250mm x 2000mm
```

Can someone please advise how to extract the two separate numbers in each case?

> 10 and 1000
>   4 and 20
>   50 and 200
>   250 and 2000

And so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly, if you have a string like 10mm, then you can use intValue to extract the 10 from it. So another way to do what you want is:

```
    NSString *s = @"10mm x 1000mm";
    NSArray *arr = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@"x"];
    int firstNum = [arr[0] intValue];
    int secondNum = [arr[1] intValue];
    NSLog(@"%d   %d",firstNum,secondNum);
```

Comment: thanks for this answer it works just as well as H2CO3's answer but is easier for me to understand

Answer (score 2):

If the format is **really, always**

```
number, "mm x ", number, "mm"
```

then you can use `NSScanner`:

```
- (void)parseString:(NSString *)str sizeX:(int *)x sizeY:(int *)y
{
    NSScanner *scn = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];
    [scn scanInt:x];
    [scn scanString:@"mm x " intoString:NULL];
    [scn scanInt:y];
}
```

and use it like:

```
NSString *s = @"50mm x 200mm";
int x, y;
[self parseString:s sizeX:&x sizeY:&y];
NSLog(@"X size: %d, Y size: %d", x, y);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer .. ive voted for rdelmar's answer only beacuse i understand it better  .. many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want something more robust, you could try regular expressions:

```
NSString * input = @"55 mm x 100mm" ;

NSRegularExpression * regex = [ NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"([0-9]+).*x.*([0-9]+)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL ] ;
NSArray * matches = [ regex matchesInString:input options:0 range:(NSRange){ .length = input.length } ] ;
NSTextCheckingResult * match = matches[0] ;

NSInteger width ;
{
    NSRange range = [ match rangeAtIndex:1 ] ;
    width = [[ input substringWithRange:range ] integerValue ] ;
}

NSInteger height ;
{
    NSRange range = [ match rangeAtIndex:2 ] ;
    height = [[ input substringWithRange:range ] integerValue ] ;
}
```